# Executar "Enviar arquivo" sem ter q clicar no input file

Tags: javascript, html

Exemplo :

Quando eu clicar no meu ícone da "câmera" :
[image: img exemplo]

Em vez de aparecer aquela pequena caixinha de "Selecionar arquivo" :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que abra direto a caixa "enviar arquivo" :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> HTML do ícone

```
<i class="material-icons icone-img">&#xE5CD;</i>
```

> HTML do formulário

```
<form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img_input" value="">
    <input id="Bot_login" type="submit" name="Trocar_img" value="Trocar imagem">
</form>
```

Comment: Basta alterar no css o input file como hidden, e atribuir o evento a outro elemento qualquer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um `label` e coloque o ícone e o `input file` dentro:

```
<label for="tipofile" class="custom-file-upload">
   <input id="tipofile" type="file" name="img_input" value="">
   <i class="material-icons icone-img">&#xE5CD;</i>
</label>
```

É preciso que o `input file` tenha uma `id` e no `label` coloque `for="id_do_input"`, conforme mostrado no exemplo acima.

E no CSS, esconda o `input file` com:

```
#tipofile{
   display: none;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
#tipofile{
   display: none;
}

/*só para exemplo*/
.icone-img{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-image: url(https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="tipofile" class="custom-file-upload">
      Clique na imagem:
      <br>
      <input id="tipofile" type="file" name="img_input" value="">
      <i class="material-icons icone-img">&#xE5CD;</i>
   </label>
    <input id="Bot_login" type="submit" name="Trocar_img" value="Trocar imagem">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
$('i.icone-img').click(() => {
  $('[name="img_input"]').click();
})
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="material-icons icone-img">&#xE5CD;</i>

<form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img_input" value="">
    <input id="Bot_login" type="submit" name="Trocar_img" value="Trocar imagem">
</form>
```